# my Resources files doesn't work in host, by Error Compiler Error Message: CS0101: The namespace 'Resources' already contains a definition

Tags: asp.net-mvc

im working on multi language web site. it works completely fine but when I upload my web site on web host it has an Error which it seems it belongs to my Resources files

my resources named these
`Ind.resx`,`Ind.fr.resx`,`Ind.jp.resx` , after I delete these two `.fr`and`.jp` index age of site will be shown but when these two is on App_GlobalResources folder site has Runtime Error for web config.
  `Compiler Error Message: CS0101: The namespace 'Resources' already contains a 
  definition for 'Ind'

Appreciate any help.
here is my web config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <configuration>
 <appSettings>
   <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
   <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
   <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
   <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
 </appSettings>
 <system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
   <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
 </system.web>
 <runtime>
   <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
     <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"/>
       <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
       </dependentAssembly>
       <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

here is my controller if needed:

```
  public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string language)
    {


        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(language) == false)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(language);
        }
        else if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(language))
        {
            try
            {
                string userIpAddress = this.Request.UserHostAddress;
                //string userIpAddress = "1.1.127.255";

                var client = new HttpClient
                {
                    BaseAddress = new Uri("http://freegeoip.net/xml/")
                };

                var response = await client.GetAsync(userIpAddress);

                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                var result = (Response)new XmlSerializer(typeof(Response)).Deserialize(new StringReader(content));
                var country_name = result.CountryName;
                var country_code = result.CountryCode;
                TempData["Country_code"] = country_code;
                TempData["Country_name"] = country_name;

                if (country_code == "FR")
                {
                    language = "fr";
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language);
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(language);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { language = language });
                }
                else if (country_code == "JP")
                {
                    language = "jp";
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language);
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(language);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { language = language });
                }
                else
                {
                    language = "en";
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language);
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(language);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { language = language });

                }


            }
            catch
            {

                language = "en";
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language);
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(language);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", new { language = language });
            }
        }

        // do stuff
        return View();


    }
```

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: Those satellite assemblies get distributed into your application's bin folder. Did you configure them to go into App_GlobalResources?

Comment: @RossBush yes Resources are in App_GlobalResources